# Flexbox: Firefox, Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css

It's my first post here, sorry if I don't understand some rules.

I have a very hard issue for me. I learn flexbox, check my code with Firefox, and work fine, but when I use chrome or safari, the IMG doesn't work with responsive and doesn't scale properly.

I uploaded the code here: https://codepen.io/JoaquinGalloUX/pen/XWRyxEm

Please check in Firefox and Chrome, I searched all over the web and I don't have the answer.

Thanks a lot for your time.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.container-imagenes {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* border: 20px solid white; */
  display: inline-flex;
  background: #DB277F;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: stretch;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.textbox {
  flex-basis: 500px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #DB277F;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.text1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.text2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.text3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#mailregs2 {
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: #008BAC;
  color: #ffff;
  ;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.imagen-1 {
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 4;
  flex-basis: 300px;
}

.imagen-2 {
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 4;
  flex-basis: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container-imagenes">

  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/300x300" class="imagen-1">
  <div class="textbox">
    <div class="text1">Suscribite a</div>
    <div class="text2">TEST!</div>
    <div class="text3">Suma puntos por TEST!</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Registrarme" id=mailregs2>
  </div>
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/300x300" class="imagen-2">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your .textclass you uses properties of flex box but you forgot about ```Display: flex;``` try this. And your style must be after the head tag so CSS can load before html.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I forgot to add " " for the img

```
  <div>
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/300x300" class= "imagen-2">
  </div>

  <div>
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/300x300" class= "imagen-1">
  </div>
```

Try in https://codepen.io/JoaquinGalloUX/pen/XWRyxEm

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the difference by changing `.container-imagenes` to `display: flex` instead of `inline-flex`.

The width calculation for inline-flex is much more complicated, as you have flex elements trying to grow to fill available space, but `inline` blocks always try to use the minimum amount of space available.
Looks like different browsers have chosen to resolve this in different ways.

By changing the flex-container to a block, the width calculations are more stable, as both the block and flex are trying to take up the available space